# Doubts about Dominated Convergence Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, lp-spaces

I am following a course of real analysis and my teacher, while proving the continuity of translation of functions in $L^p$, used the dominated convergence theorem (DCT) in a strange way. I write the first half of proof, for being clear.

> Given $f \in L^p(E)$, with $E$ measurable and $1\le p< \infty$, then for every $\varepsilon >0$ exists $\delta=\delta(\varepsilon)$ such that 
>   $$ \Vert T_hf-f\Vert_p<\varepsilon \ \ \text{ if}\ \ \vert h \vert < \delta $$
>   Where the operator $T_hf$ is defined by
>   $$ T_hf(x)=
> \begin{cases}
> f(x+h) & \text{if}\ x+h \in E, \\
> 0       & \text{if}\ x+h \in \mathbb{R}^N-E 
> \end{cases} $$

Proof.First we may suppose $f$ continuous and compactly supported (and at the end of the proof uses the density of such functions in $L^p$). For all $x \in E$ we have that $$ \vert T_hf(x)- f(x)\vert^p=\vert f(x+h)-f(x) \vert^p \to 0 \ \ \text{if}\ \ \vert h \vert \to 0$$
Now $f$ is continuous and compactly supported, so $\Vert f \Vert_\infty < \infty$, than we can write
$$ \vert T_hf(x)- f(x)\vert^p \le \left(\vert f(x+h)\vert+\vert f(x) \vert\right)^p \le 2^p \Vert f \Vert_\infty$$
So, letting $K$ be the compact support of $f$ and $\vert h\vert < \delta$, we have that the function $\vert T_hf-f \vert$ vanishes outside the set $K_\delta=K+B(0,\delta)$ (the ball centered in $0$ with radius $\delta$), that is measurable. So we can dominate
$$ \vert T_hf-f \vert \le 2^p \Vert f \Vert_\infty \chi_{K_\delta}$$
Now using the DCT we can say that $\Vert T_hf-f \Vert_p <\varepsilon$ for $|h|<\delta$.
For $f \in L^p(E)$ generic we use the density of continuous and compactly supported functions.

The DCT is true for numerable families of functions $\{f_n \}$, but here is used for a non-countable family $\{f_t\}_{t \in I \subseteq \mathbb{R}}$, such $T_hf$. I managed as follow for giving a sense to the proof.

The DCT states that if we have a sequences of measurable function $f_n$ such that $f_n \to f$ pointwise, and all functions $f_n$ are "dominated" by a summable function $g$, i.e $|f_n(x)| \le |g(x)|, \ \forall n, \ \forall x$, so
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{E} f_{n} d \mu= \int_{E} f d \mu$$
Now we have a subset $I$ of real numbers (we suppose for semplicity $I$ as interval), and a family of function $\{f_t\}_{t \in I}$ (dominated by a summable function $g$). Consider the function 
$$
\begin{aligned}
\phi \colon I &\longrightarrow \mathbb{R} \\
t &\longmapsto \int_{E}f_t d \mu
\end{aligned} 
$$
Now suppose we have the property that, fixed $\bar t \in I$, for every sequences $\{t_n\} \subseteq I$ such that $t_n  \to \bar t$ as $n$ increase, result that $f_{t_n} \to f_{t}$ poinwise. By DCT we have that 
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\phi(t_n) = \phi(\bar t)$$
for every sequence $t_n$ convergent to $\bar t$. So for a well known theorem of topology, we have
$$ \lim_{t \to \bar t} \phi(t)=\phi(\bar t) $$

Choosing $\phi(h)=T_hf$ and $\bar t=0$ we have concluded the problem.

Because I don't have practice with $L^p$ space my question is if the above reasoning is right or not.
My teacher use that fact easy, without long arguments, so there may be a faster reasoning way?

Thank you a lot.

Comment: Is it not easier to use an $\frac{\epsilon}{3}$ argument?

Comment: @ Chris: judging from the first paragraph, I'd guess $T_h(x) = f(x-h)$.

Comment: @Christipher you are right, indeed I added the definition of $T_hf$ operator.

Comment: @Vivek, Yes the proof ends with a $\varepsilon/3$ argument.

Comment: @Lorban I'm not sure what TCD is. and where exactly is your professor claiming to use DCT?

Comment: I said it in the following step after seeing that $|T_hf-f|$ is dominated.
TCD was the DCT (dominated convergence theorem), I'm italian and the we use the abbreviation TCD (teorema convergenza dominata). This is the cause of my notation mistake. I'll correct, sorry.

Comment: $f$ being compactly supported does not imply that $\|f\|_{ L^\infty}\lt\infty$. $f(x)=\frac1{\sqrt{|x|}}1_{[-1,1]}$ is compactly supported, in $L^p$ for $p<2$, yet not in $L^\infty$.

Comment: For sure, whenever I said that a function was compactly supported, I meant that was also continuous. In particular at the step corrected by robjohn, I used the fact that a continuous function $f \colon K \to \mathbb{R}$ is limited if $K$ compact. Now I'll add the right hypothesis of continuity.
Sorry for all these mistakes.

Comment: ps @robjohn thank you for your example, though simple, is nice!
I hope now what I wrote is clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your reasoning was more or less what your teacher had in mind. Actually, was we have to show is that for each sequence $\{h_n\}$ converging to $0$, we have $\lVert \tau_{h_n}f-f\rVert_{L^p}\to 0$. It's enough to reach the conclusion, as if it was not true, there would be an $\varepsilon$ such that if $\delta>0$, we can find $|h|<\delta$ such that $\lVert \tau_{h}f-f\rVert_{L^p}\geqslant \varepsilon$. In particular, taking $\delta=\frac 1n$ for $n$ integer, we find a sequence $\{h_n\}$ converging to $0$ such that $\lVert \tau_{h_n}f-f\rVert_{L^p}\geqslant \varepsilon$, a contradiction.

Comment: Sure, but we need that $\{\tau_{h_n}f \}$ has to converge to $f$ for every sequence $\{h_n\}$ converging to $0$, that is obviously true in this case.
In general with a family $\{ f_t\}_{t \in I}$ with $I=[0,1]$ (for example) is used that $f_t$ converges to $f_0$ with continuity respect to $t$, and this is true if for every sequence $t_n$ converging to $0$, we have that $f_{t_n}$ converge to $f_0$, for the same theorem I mentioned above.
I hope you understand what I mean.